# Create and redirect to slug urls in django

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, slug

I have doctor profiles on my app and would like to create slug urls for all of them. So I've the following questions

1. How do I create slug urls for the new doctors and as well as existing doctors in the database?

The url looks like this `http://localhost:8000/docprofile/6/`

and I want to make it like this `http://localhost:8000/doctor/james-smith/`

I want the slug to be based on the name of the doctor

2. How do I do a permanent url redirection after implementing slug urls such that if a person goes to `http://localhost:8000/docprofile/6/`, the page is redirected to `http://localhost:8000/doctor/james-smith/`

Here is the models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)

    def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s %s" % (self.name, self.specialization)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('kk1.views.showDocProfile', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
def showDocProfile(request, id):
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)
    clinic = Clinic.objects.get(id=doctor.clinic.id)

    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': doctor.name +" "+ doctor.specialization.name +" -})


    d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'clinic': clinic,'form': form })
    return render(request, 'kk1/docprofile.html', d)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^docprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile'),
```

Answer (score 1):

First question:

```
url(r'^doctor/(?P<name>\w+)/$', views.showDocProfileByName),
```

Second question:

```
def showDocProfileById(request, id):
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)
    name = doctor.name.replace(' ', '-')

    HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project.views.showDocProfileByName', args=(name)))
```

Comment: Exception Type: AttributeError at /docprofile/6/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'showDocProfileByName'

Comment: Yes, you need to also add `showDocProfileByName` function to your `views.py`. The function should be very similar to `showDocProfile` so try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could just allow the user to input either id or doctor name

```
url(r'^docprofile/(?P<identifier>(\d+|\w+))', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile')
```